# Creating Sandbox Account in PayPal developer returns error status

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm trying to create a sandbox app to use for paypal checkout.

I go to Create app page but nothing is shown in the account dropdown:

[image]

As the error message says:

```
To create an application, you must create a business sandbox account. If you already have a business sandbox account, it may be in an error state, and you might need to create another sandbox account.
```

So I went to PayPal developer Sandbox > Accounts > Create Account

I already had 2 predefined accounts - personal & business - (not sure where from cos I don't remember creating them) and indeed their status showed 'error'. I created another business account but that returned with error status. So I deleted all of them and tried to recreate business account. In vain - it gets into processing status and when I refresh it says Status: error:

[image]

I tried different options both personal & busines account, US, non-US etc. but everything gets error status.
On the Profile account details it says `Your sandbox account could not be created. Delete it and try again.`

Not sure how it's possible to create the account at all? Anybody got through this experience successfully?

Comment: @PayPal_Jared I will appreciate help

Comment: this is not an uncommon issue. It's happened to me quite a bit. My work around was I cleared out my sessions, tried an incognito session and it worked. Sometimes I had to just wait and go back at a later time; again, clearing cached/cookie info from browser. Might want to try a different browser that doesn't have any paypal login stored info as well.

Comment: Clearing the cache and cookies didn't help me I tried already. But did it from my Mac (instead of Win OS) and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: cool, glad you got it dude. l8tr!

Comment: One year later, I am having the exact same issue and there is still no clear path forward. A telling example about how incompetent Paypal is.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the ""Create Account" button - instead of duplicating. 
  There seems to be a number of bugs if you use the **Actions "Duplicate"** method of generating a new sandbox account.

Paypal - provides  two examples for you when you first visit the sandbox accounts section.

If you use the **Actions "Duplicate"** of one of those accounts - which is the natural tendency.
It seems to have a number of errors in the fields.

Programmatic errors - it set the sandbox **account balance**, as my **user name** and would not accept the email address.

It also seemed to want to check that the selected email/username did not already exist. Wait till you see the green "available" text when you enter the email address/username

*Overall - it just seemed buggy - take your time an create new accounts. Some sloppy programming and management on paypals part. Big surprize. 0_0

*It took multiple attempts - deleting the test sandbox account I tried to create - and then starting over and trying again.

It is likely that these errors will eventually be fixed - but as of today (Aug 09 2017) this is what worked for me. And the errors mentioned existed.